# Why git fetch doesn't work

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Forgive me I just started to use git. I have cloned the master on my local system using `git clone`. It works fine. When I tried to update my local clone using `git fetch`(before I tried it , I deleted some files in my clone for testing, and hope `git fetch` can download the deleted files from git again).It doesn't work.

I have a quick query how to update my clone from the master. I tried `git pull`. It did not work, the deleted files doesn't appear again.  How I can update the clone? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the deleted files back, you can do:

```
git checkout .
```

What `git fetch` does:

> git-fetch - Download objects and refs from another repository

Basically it downloads VCS updates from remotes. When you delete files from your work tree, they are not deleted from the repository. So for `git fetch` there is nothing to download, and it will do nothing when you run it.

What `git pull` does:

> git-pull - Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch

Basically it does `git fetch` and a `git merge`.

Comment: +1 Thanks your kindly help. If someone not me added files into repository master. Should I use to `git fetch` or `git checkout` to get latest update ? thanks.

Comment: You'll need to do `git fetch` to download the updated VCS info to your PC. For example if your remote is called `origin`, then `git fetch origin` will fetch the updates from it. If others made changes, then `origin/master` will be different from your local `master`. You can either `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master` to get those changes in your branch.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I need read more to know about something like what is the remote. what is the VCS etc .. Could you please help to give me some to read ? It will be appreciated . Thanks.